# Rename files to change punctuation and numbering

Tags: files, scripting, rename

I need a command to recursively rename a large number of jpg files in Ubuntu.

However there are some problems. A normal group of files would look like `ani-estate-villas_1431640729_3.jpg`, `ani-estate-villa_3627544278_7.jpg` and `ani-estate-villa_3143254376_5.jpg`

I need to replace all `-` with `_`, remove all numbers and then add numbering which resets in every directory. So the same group of files should look like `ani_estate_villas_1.jpg`, `ani_estate_villas_2.jpg`, `ani_estate_villas_3.jpg` and the same with the other files in the other directories.

The depth of the recursion is 1 or 2 directories deep, so you might find a `directory/file.jpg` or `directory/directory/file.jpg` it's pretty much random.

Running a command in every directory with jpgs is also doable so if anyone has any idea on how to rename all files with those characteristics would be fine. Although running one single command is cooler, I'd much appreciate a bit more repetitive solution, because manually changing the 400+ jpg files is too much.

I tried using krename but it deletes my files.

Comment: It's certainly doable.  Just to clarify, small question: `ani-estate-villas_1431640729_3` should be reduced to `ani_estate_villas_3` , or the last number should be somehow different based on other files?

Comment: Yep the last number must be a file numbering that starts over in every directory with jpg files.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify your question.

Comment: You mention file names that end with `_` and a number, and file names that end with `.jpg`. Which is it?

Comment: They're all .jpg. Will edit to clarify

Comment: @Gilles . I edited the question to clarify

Comment: @Serg I edited the question to clarify, thanks!

Comment: If you have  `bar_456.jpg`, `foo_123.jpg`, `foo_789.jpg` in the same directory, do you want to end up with `bar_1.jpg`, `foo_2.jpg` and `foo_3.jpg`? with `bar_1.jpg`, `foo_1.jpg` and `foo_2.jpg`? with `foo_1.jpg`, `bar_2.jpg` and `foo_3.jpg`? In other words, how are the numbers chosen when there are multiple prefixes?

Comment: @Gilles all strings between `-` remain the same, only that the `-` are changed for `_`. The last number is just to number the files and this should resetted in each directory. So basically `foo-bar_3624_3`, `foo-bar_3844_8` and `foo-bar_5644_3` should be `foo_bar_1`, `foo_bar_2` and `foo_bar_3`

Comment: But what if you have different prefixes? Is there a single numbering sequence in each directory, or one per prefix? And if there's a single numbering sequence, how are the files ordered?

Comment: @Gilles there could be one or many prefixes. It could be foo_3627_3.jpg or foo-bar_36275_7.jpg. So it should be able to change the `-` to `_` in case of two or more prefixes, remove the long numbers and then add a file numbering that resets in every directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/prename.1.html) command to rename files based on a transformation written in [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl).

Let's start simple. To rename all the `.jpg` files in a directory, changing all `-` to `_`, we can just use the [`s` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2fmsixpodualngcer) (we could also use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2f_SEARCHLIST_%2f_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2fcdsr)). The Perl code is executed to transform each file name.

```
prename 's!-!_!g' *.jpg
```

To change the number sequence(s) at the end to a simple counter, we introduce a counter variable. I use the global variable `$a` as a counter (introducing extra variables is more complicated). The regular expression `(\.[^/.]*)$` matches the file extension, and `$1` in the replacement text stands for what the parenthesized group matched.

```
prename 's!-!_!g; ++$a; s!_[0-9_]+(\.[^/.]*)$!_$a$1!' *.jpg
```

Note that the files are renamed in the order given by the file name arguments, i.e. the order of expansion of `*.jpg` determines the numbering of the files.

Alternatively, we can initialize the counter explicitly with a `BEGIN` block.

```
prename 'BEGIN {$a = 1;} s!-!_!g; s!_[0-9_]+(\.[^/.]*)$!_$a$1!; ++$a;' *.jpg
```

To perform this in every subdirectory of the current directory, call [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/find.1.html).

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && prename "$0" *.jpg' 's!-!_!g; ++$a; s!_[0-9_]+(\.[^/.]*)$!_$a$1!' {} \;
```

Comment: It's 2am here so I'm going to bed, but will give it a try first thing tomorrow. It seems it'll work, I really hope it does :). Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

Global symbol "$c" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $c"?) at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you :)

Comment: also, what version of perl are you using? Thanks!

Comment: @HenryOllarves Oh, oops. Variables are local by default. Use `$a`, which owing to Perl's idiosyncrasies is always a global variable.